# Tikz example doesn't compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I tested this example (from tikz package) [example's link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/) and my IDE TexMaker with MiKTeX returns an error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/edge from parent fork dow
```

I aalo tested this one : [example's link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/) and I have this error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/grow via three points' an
```

Then, I check and all my packages seem to be updated with the last versions... I really don't understand what's the problem.

Thks.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot `\usetikzlibrary{trees}` in the preamble.

Comment: welcome to the site. The example works fine for me- perhaps an [update is in order](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Comment: I don't forget to include `\usetikzlibrary{trees}` I use Windows 7 64 bits, I use MiKTeX 2.9 with TexMaker...

Comment: Try to download the latest version from CTAN http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have only installed basic MiKTeX.  Basic MiKTeX has only a few packages.  Install the complete MiKTeX to compile the TiKZ examples without errors or use MiKTeX package manager to install all needed packages for the TiKZ examples.